# Problema con PHP

Tags: php, html

Tengo un codigo HTML para enviar un formulario que lleva una fotografía.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="imagen_subir" id="imagen_subir">
    <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-danger" name="submit_perfil" value="<?php echo $id ?>">Cambiar fotografía</button>
</form>
```

El código PHP al momento de enviar es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit_perfil'])){
        $id_per = $_POST['submit_perfil'];
        $directorio_objetivo = "personas/";
        $archivo_objetivo2 = $directorio_objetivo.basename($_FILES["imagen_subir"]["name"]);
        $archivo_objetivo = $directorio_objetivo.basename($_FILES["imagen_subir"]["name"]="perfil_".$_SESSION['token_per'].".".pathinfo($archivo_objetivo2,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $estado_subida = 1;
        $tipo_de_archivo = pathinfo($archivo_objetivo,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $comprobar = getimagesize($_FILES["imagen_subir"]["tmp_name"]);
            if ($comprobar !== false){
                //echo "El archivo es una imagen - ".$comprobar["mime"].'.';
                $estado_subida=1;
            }else{
                //echo "El archivo no es una imagen";
                $estado_subida=0;
            }
        }
        //if (file_exists($archivo_objetivo)){
        //  echo "El archivo ya es existente";
        //  $estado_subida=0;
        //}
        if ($_FILES["imagen_subir"]["size"]>5000000){
            //echo "Perdona, el archivo es demasiado grande";
            $estado_subida=0;
        }
        if ($tipo_de_archivo != "jpg"){
            //echo "Debes subir una imagen";
            $estado_subida=0;
        }
        if ($estado_subida==0){
            //echo "Tu archivo no pudo ser subido";
        }else{
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen_subir"]["tmp_name"], $archivo_objetivo)){
                ?>
                <section class="predeterminada-seccion">
                    <h1 style="text-align:center;">La imagen de perfil ha sido correctamente cambiada :)</h1>
                    <a href="subir.php" class="form-control btn btn-primary">Cambiar fotografía nuevamente</a>
                </section>
                <?php
            }else{
                ?>
                <section class="predeterminada-seccion">
                    <h1 style="text-align:center;">El archivo no pudo cargarse. Por favor intentar más tarde.</h1>
                </section>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }?>
```

Hay un problema cuando en el dispositivo móvil (Android) se elije la opcion de tomar fotografía.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La aplicación usada para la toma de la fotografía es "Retrica", con la aplicación de cámara nativa funciona perfecto.
Al tomar la fotografía y enviarla, la imagen queda con rotación de 90° en contra de las agujas del relog.
Por qué pasa esto?
Pude lograr cambiar el nombre del archivo que se está subiendo, y la verdad es que no tengo idea de como lo hice. Jaja, igual no es importante.
Sólo necesito saber por qué la imagen queda rotada.
Hay algún fix o tengo un error en el código?
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La imagen queda rotada debido a los metatags [EXIF](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html), en tu caso 90° en contra de las agujas es el flag `6`. Con la función [`exif_read_data()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) podrías obtener el valor de este flag. Por ejemplo:

```
$exif = exif_read_data($archivo_objetivo);
$orientacion = $exif['IFD0']['Orientation'];
```

Este problema probablemente ocurre también con dispositivos iOS y no sólo Android.

Comment: Lo intentaré, gracias.